# Return Coq type from an xml and write a parsing function in OCaml

Tags: xml, ocaml, coq

```
 <xs:element name="lhs">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="state"/>
        </xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="state"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

From this xsds I return a `Coq` type, where if it is `<choice>` tag I return an `Inductive` type, for example:

```
Inductive lhs = 
 | Lhs_lhs : list state -> lhs
 | Lhs_state : state -> lhs.
```

At the first constructor `Lhs_lhs` I force it generates for me as type above. Because tag `<sequence>` has no tag name.

After that I write a function to parse this xsds in `OCaml`:

```
let rec lhs x = get_son "lhs" lhs_val

and lhs_val xs = match xs with
  | Element ("", _, _, xs) -> 
   let item_state, xs = parse_list state xs in
     check_emptyness xs;
   Lhs_lhs (item_state)
  | Element ("state", _, _, xs) -> Lhs_state (state_val xs)
  | x -> error_xml x "it is not a lhs";;
```

where `parse_list` :

```
let try_parse parse x = try Some (parse x) with Error _ -> None;;

(* parses the biggest prefix of `xs` with the
  (parse) function, i.e. it returns the pair `(is, xs2)` such that:
         - xs = xs1 @ xs2
         - `is = List.map parse xs1`
        `- xs1` is as big as possible *)
let parse_list parse =
  let rec aux is = function
    | [] -> List.rev is, []
    | (hd :: tl) as xs ->
    match try_parse parse hd with
      | Some i -> aux (i::is) tl
      | None -> List.rev is, xs
  in aux [];;

 (* check that there is nothing else to parse; raises an error
   otherwise. *)
    let check_emptyness = function
      | x :: _ -> error_xml x "unexpected element"
      | [] -> ();;

let get_son tag f = function
  | Element (t, _, _, x :: _) when t = tag -> f x
  | (PCData _ | Element _) as x -> error_xml x ("not a " ^ tag);;
```

Here is my question:
At the function `lhs_val` the first constructor I cannot get it right to go to the function inside `item_state` because it is not an empty `Element ("", _, _, xs)`. I tried to parse it as:

```
and lhs_val xs = match xs with
  | xs -> 
   let item_state, xs = parse_list state xs in
     check_emptyness xs;
   Lhs_lhs (item_state)
  | Element ("state", _, _, xs) -> Lhs_state (state_val xs)
```

I got an error at `parse_list state xs` because it is an `xml` but the function was expected an `xml list`.

Could you please help me to find a way to solve this situation? Whether I could change the `Coq` type or other ways? etc. Thank you very much for your help.